# Fixing mismatch between PROJ version and proj.db?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

When transforming the CRS in QGIS, I get the following error: *No transform available between EPSG:32722 and Custom CRS* (or any CRS). When I click on *Details*, I read the following message:

> No transform is available between EPSG:32722 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 22S
> and Custom CRS: GEOGCRS["unknown",DATUM["unknown",ELLIPSOID["WGS 8….
>
> proj_create_operations: SQLite error on SELECT name, type,
> coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name,
> datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition,
> deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such
> column: area_of_use_auth_name

After some searching online, I found that the problem is likely due to a mismatch between the PROJ version and the proj.db: "You're likely  using a PROJ < 8 library with a proj.db from PROJ 7.2 or 8. Check PROJ_LIB" (https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2020-December/053177.html).

EDIT: I might have caused this problem myself when I tried to solve another problem related to dpkg. I used the solution offered in this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309161/dpkg-error-processing-package-qgis-providers-configure. This might have led to the current error I'm describing here.

However, I cannot find the solution for fixing this mismatch. What should I do to make the PROJ library work again? Downgrade the current installation, or do something with the proj.db?

QGIS installation information:

[image]

Output of the command `proj -v`:

```
proj_create: unrecognized format / unknown name
Rel. 8.2.0, November 1st, 2021
<proj>: 
projection initialization failure
cause: Unknown error (code 4096)
program abnormally terminated
```

Comment: Scan your file system if you happen to have several Proj versions installed. In that case setting PROJ_LIB to point to suitable version should help. If you have only Proj 8.2.0 and QGIS is compiled to use 6.3.1 you must either downgrade Proj or install QGIS that is compiled to use newer Proj. What is your operating system?

Comment: Thanks, I will try that! My OS is Linux Mint 20.3.

Comment: See my edit. I also tried downgrading, but when running `sudo apt-get -t=6.3.1 install proj`, I get the error message `E: The value '6.3.1' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a mess with different versions of PROJ. That's bad. And you are having problems to install the package 6.3.1.

As a first try you can get the file `proj.db` from the tarball for that release https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/releases/tag/6.3.1 and set the environment variable `PROJ_LIB` pointing to the directory where you place it. If you want to use grid files, they should be in that env var as well (separate the folder paths with `:` in your case -linux-)

If that works, try to set a more stable configuration for your system.

Maybe you need as well the library (libproj.so.15.3.1). In this case using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` may help you.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question, but I had to solve the same problem of a mismatching proj.db version and have succeeded in a workaround.

I had to:

- download the deb package containing the matching proj.db
- Manually install the database to a custom location
- When running QGIS, set the PROJ_LIB environment variable to point at the matching proj.db

Example manual installation is:

```
mkdir proj
apt download proj-data=6.3.1-1
dpkg-deb --extract proj-data_6.3.1-1_all.deb ./proj
sudo mkdir /usr/share/proj-6.3.1
sudo cp ./proj/usr/share/proj/* /usr/share/proj-6.3.1
rm proj-data_6.3.1-1_all.deb
rm -r proj
```

To run QGIS then use:

```
PROJ_LIB=/usr/share/proj-6.3.1 qgis
```

My problem was caused by having QGIS 3.26.3 (compiled against proj 6.3.1) and proj 7.2.1.